# No output on command line python

Tags: python, command-line

This is my code. when I run it, it simply exits after running. There is nothing printed.  Why so ?

```
def checkString(filename, string):
    input = file(filename) # read only will be default file permission
    found = False
    searchString = string
    for line in input:
        if searchString in line:
            found = True
            break

if callfunc == 'initialize':
    print listdir() #this will print list of files
    print "\n"

for files in listdir():
    checkString(files,"hello")

if found:
    print "String found"
else:
    print "String not found"
input.close()
```

Comment: @erjoalgo, sorry. Its repy/seattle.  listdir is built-in function which lists every file in current directory.

Answer (score 0):

`found` is a *local* name in the function `checkString()`; it stays local because you don't return it.

Return the variable from the function and store the return value:

```
def checkString(filename, string):
    input = file(filename) # read only will be default file permission
    found = False
    searchString = string
    for line in input:
        if searchString in line:
            found = True
            break
    return found

for files in listdir():
    found = checkString(files,"hello")
    if found:
        print "String found"
    else:
        print "String not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify to:

```
def checkString(filename, string):
    input = file(filename) # read only will be default file permission
    found = False
    searchString = string
    for line in input:
        if searchString in line:
            found = True
            break

    input.close()
    return found

found = False

if callfunc == 'initialize':
    print listdir() #this will print list of files
    print "\n"

for files in listdir():
    found = found or checkString(files,"hello")

if found:
    print "String found"
else:
    print "String not found"
```

This is because in your original `found` is only in scope within the function `checkString`